# how to UnRegistered from Google Cloud Messaging Client in Android App

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I develop an Android App in xamarin environment with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) and Azure Notification Hub.

The problem is: I don't know how to unsubscribe from previous tags. Even when I uninstall an install again -  the app continue receiving notifications for each tag I have suscribed previously.

meybe I need to implement the function:

```
protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: You have to make a broadcast receiver which will check your updating app and in that broadcast receiver you can make a call like this `if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(context)) {
    GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
   }`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister%28%29

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to Unregister at Azure Notification Hub.

```
protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
    if (hub != null)
        hub.Unregister();
}
```

where `hub` is the same `NotificationHub` which you used in `OnRegistered`

Answer (score 0):

Use `unregister()` method of `GoogleCloudMessaging` to stop receiving GCM message.

```
protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId){
     //Run on background
     GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context).unregister();
}
```

> **[public void unregister ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#unregister%28%29)**
>
> Unregister the application. Calling unregister() stops any messages
>   from the server. This is a blocking call—you shouldn't call it from
>   the UI thread. You should rarely (if ever) need to call this method.
>   Not only is it expensive in terms of resources, but it invalidates
>   your registration ID, which should never change unnecessarily. A
>   better approach is to simply have your server stop sending messages.
>   Only use unregister if you want your application to stop using GCM
>   permanently, or you have a compelling reason to recycle your
>   registration ID. Throws IOException if we can't connect to server to
>   unregister.

Comment: you'd better explain why your answer solves his problem